# Microsoft BotFramework: How to send raw JSON message to channels?

Tags: node.js, botframework

I'm using Node.js and BotBuilder v3.1.1.

Previously, we had `Session.sendMessage();` that we could use to send raw data to the channel we are connected with.

That proved useful for quick testing and using new features that aren't implemented on the library yet.

How can I do this on the current version v3, since the sendMessage method was removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what your after, as I was looking for something similar myself. What's needed is **sourceEvent** which is replacing **channelData**. I'm aware this card can be made by the builder but for an example it works fine.

```
bot.dialog('/', [
function (session) {
    var msg = new builder.Message(session).sourceEvent({
            facebook: {
                    notification_type: "REGULAR",
                    attachment: {
                        type: "template",
                        payload: {
                            template_type: "generic",
                            elements: [{
                                title: "Some Title",
                                image_url: "http://docs.botframework.com/images/demo_bot_image.png",
                                subtitle: "Some amazing subtitle",
                                buttons: [{
                                    type: "postback",
                                    title: "GO",
                                    payload: "demo"
                                }]
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                }
        });
    session.send(msg);
}
]);
```

Works great for Facebook, at least in my tests. One thing I'm struggling with is how to handle the postback from the button in node.

**Update:** So I answered my own secondary question about the postback [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38556885/how-to-handle-postback-from-facebook-sourceevent-botframework-node).

Cheers,

Comment: Yeah it did work! Thanks :) On my tests, the payload gets sent as a message as if the user had sent it. I'm struggling with the account_linking process. Are you using it?

Comment: Great, I'm glad that helped. As for account_linking, I might need to soon but I have no experience with it I'm afraid, something I've got to look forward to I guess :).