# How to handle postback from Facebook sourceEvent botframework node

Tags: node.js, facebook, botframework

So as mentioned in the title I need to figure out how to handle a postback from the user tapping/clicking a button in facebook messenger. I'm aware this card can be handled with a bot builder card but there are some other elements I want to test too. Please see the following code:

```
bot.dialog('/', [
function (session) {
    var msg = new builder.Message(session).sourceEvent({
            facebook: {
                    notification_type: "REGULAR",
                    attachment: {
                        type: "template",
                        payload: {
                            template_type: "generic",
                            elements: [{
                                title: "Title here",
                                image_url: "http://docs.botframework.com/images/demo_bot_image.png",
                                subtitle: "Subtitle here",
                                buttons: [{
                                    type: "postback",
                                    title: "GO",
                                    payload: "dosomething"
                                }]
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                }
        });
    session.send(msg);
},
function(session, results){
    session.send(JSON.stringify(results));
    session.send(JSON.stringify(session));
}
]);
```

So basically once the user clicks the 'GO' button I want to action another dialog in node, the card works but I just don't know how to handle it. I thought it might work with the waterfall but the shown code didn't return anything.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've pulled my head out of the clouds and answered my own question. The clue was in the button type: `type: "postback"`.

See the following:

```
bot.dialog('/', [
    function (session) {
        var msg = new builder.Message(session).sourceEvent({
                facebook: {
                        notification_type: "REGULAR",
                        attachment: {
                            type: "template",
                            payload: {
                                template_type: "generic",
                                elements: [{
                                    title: "Great title",
                                    image_url: "http://docs.botframework.com/images/demo_bot_image.png",
                                    subtitle: "Even better subtitle",
                                    buttons: [{
                                        type: "postback",
                                        title: "GO",
                                        payload: "action?stacktest"
                                    }]
                                }]
                            }
                        }
                    }
            });
        session.send(msg);
    }
]);
```

So all I've done is posted back the action 'stacktest' and handled it with the following:

```
bot.beginDialogAction('stacktest', '/stacktest');
bot.dialog('/stacktest', function(session){
    session.send("Woot, stacktest worked a treat.");
});
```

Hope this helps someone.

Cheers.