# MS Bot: How to create custom cards

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

Is it possible to create custom cards like Hero Card or extend the existing ones of Hero Card (Carousel Model), add some more fields?

Comment: https://blog.botframework.com/2017/05/10/Build/

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. The cards translate to what the messaging platforms can display natively. You can send raw JSON if your channel of choice supports something that the bot framework doesn't have an abstraction for:

[Microsoft BotFramework: How to send raw JSON message to channels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38490287/microsoft-botframework-how-to-send-raw-json-message-to-channels)

Comment: The github link on the NPM gives me 404. Has it not been made public yet? https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards. And the render2image link is also dead. Is it so new that it's not been fully published yet?

Answer (score 0):

Please check out http://adaptivecards.io

Some docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-add-rich-card-attachments

`Adaptive Cards` enable adding `TextBlocks`, different `Input` types, define `Submit` or `OpenUrl` Actions, and tons of customizations.

There's nuget and npm packages:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AdaptiveCards/

https://www.npmjs.com/package/microsoft-adaptivecards

and the source is on GitHub: https://github.com/Microsoft/AdaptiveCards